# Searching on multiple fields of different tables

Tags: java, mysql, search

I have a web interface(jsp), two tables(mysql) and I am dealing with Java.

1st table consists of employee details and 2nd table has project details.
Both tables are cross referenced by `empId` and `prjId`.

On web, I want to give an interface from where user can search on for any employee on the basis of `emp_name(empTable)`, `prj_name(prjTable)`, `technology(empTable)` or on combination of these fields.

First I think of doing it with joins but not working.
Later I thought of creating an extra table consists of complete details and then apply search query on that but it creating problem when I was trying to do combine search.
And in last I will try to write complex search queries and nested queries to do so but it is really complex that's why before writing that quires I think it is better to ask it here if there is any better way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What kind of backend are you using? Spring MVC? If so use hibernate

Comment: what is the problem with the join? it's only 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Depends which way you want your clients to use your "service".

For instance, you could provide an `EmployeeService` interface:

```
public interface EmployeeService {
    public Employee getEmployee(int empId);
    public Employee getEmployee(String name);
    public List<Project> getProjects(int empId);
}
```

Perhaps also a `ProjectService`:

```
public interface ProjectService {
    public List<Project> getProjects();
    public List<Project> getProjects(int projectId);
}
```

Implementations of these classes could work anyway you want. If it's a simple model, you may just consider putting in an abstraction that deals with querying that part of your model (table). This follows the Data Access Object pattern (DAO):

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao = ...;

    public Employee getEmployee(int empId) {
        return employeeDao.getEmployee(empId);
    }
    ...
}
```

and the supporting `EmployeeDAO`:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
  public Employee getEmployee(int empId) {  //try/catch omitted
      Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(...);
      ...
      ResultSet rs = stmt.execute();
      return buildEmployee(rs);
  }

  //etc...
}
```

And `ProjectDAO`:
    public class ProjectDAOImpl implements ProjectDAO {
        ...
    }

You can see that the above interfaces indicate a class to encapsulate the data you're dealing with - `Employee`s and `Project`s. Also note that the `EmployeeService` pertains to employee activity - so, you can also ask it to get the projects for an employee. It can delegate this query to the `ProjectDAO` to execute.

The main point is, you keep your interface clean of query specifics and hide the distinction of the data underneath. Services provide the access. The `DAO`s provide the data access. The data itself is housed in the model oblects - `Employee` and `Project`. You may choose to keep an `Employee`s `Project` data inside or outside the `Employee` class, as you wish. There are tradeoffs.

Note also that `DAO`s have been overtaken by the notion of object-relational framworks - where the underlying database structure is mapped to real objects and the integration managed by the framework. See **JPA** (Java Persistence Framework) and **Hibernate** in the java world (although what I'd give for Apple's old EOF framework!).

Selecting between raw JDBC and JPA (or Hibernate) though is a matter of tradeoffs. Simplicity may lend itself to JDBC. In either case, if you're learning - start with a JDBC approach so you know what goes on under the hood and then reimplment your services using JPA.

This should hopefully give you some pointers to an approach to do the operations you're after though. A follow up point might be to make your JSP not use your bean directly (your services). You might make them **ReST services** instead.